# Getting multiple pages of results from AWS DynamoDB with iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Let me preface this question by saying that I'm very new to coding with Swift and in iOS in general.  I've got some experience in Java/Android and am starting to work with iOS as well now.

I need to query a dynamodb table with enough data in it that Amazon paginates the results (I think the limit is 100kb).  Using the limited examples for AWS/Swift I am able to query that table but only successfully retrieve the first page of data.  My question is how to get that 2nd, 3rd, etc page of data.  See code below

```
let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
        queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "venue_event = :ev"
        queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":ev" : "event"]

        dynamoDBObjectMapper.query(Event.self, expression: queryExpression).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: {(task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            let results = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput 
            for r in results.items{
                print (r)
            }
            return nil
        })
```

I've noticed that 'results' has a lastEvaluatedKey variable and loadNextPage method.  However I can't seem to get either to give me the function I'm looking for

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
var paginatedOutput: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?
...
    self.paginatedOutput = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput 
...

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NoSQLQueryResultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NoSQLQueryResultCell
    ...
    if (!loading) && (paginatedOutput?.lastEvaluatedKey != nil) && indexPath.section == self.results!.count - 1 {
        self.loadMoreResults()
    }
    return cell

}

func loadMoreResults() {
    loading = true
    paginatedOutput?.loadNextPageWithCompletionHandler({(error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to load more results: \(error)")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.showAlertWithTitle("Error", message: "Failed to load more more results: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            })
        }
        else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.results!.appendContentsOf(self.paginatedOutput!.items)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.loading = false
            })
        }
    })
}
```

You can download MobileHub Sample code:

[image]

This map help:

[image]